# Separator in a SplitView Pane

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have created a SplitView, but I have a problem in defining a Separator for the menu Option in the SplitView Pane like this in Groove Musique application:

[image]

I tried to use a Line shape, but I think that is not a solution.

How can I define this kind of separator in my SplitView Pane?

Comment: thanks Sir worldofjr for the edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Windows 10 SplitView – Build Your First Hamburger Menu](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/quick_thoughts/archive/2015/06/01/windows-10-build-your-first-hamburger-menu.aspx) as a guide, I have adapted it as shown below using a Border and a Rectangle to achieve a separator.

[image: Hamburger Menu With Separator]

```
<SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"  IsPaneOpen="False" 
       CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="150">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel Background="Gray">
            <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;"
             Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="MenuButton1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE825;"
             Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Button 1" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,0"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="MenuButton2" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE10F;"
                 Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Button 2" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Blue" Height="4" Margin="4,0"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="MenuButton3" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE1D6;"
                 Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Button 3" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Separator Hamburger Menu Test"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the sample above is a bit outdated not ready for the real world. You can try my sample shown here...
https://bernhardelbl.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/hamburger-menu-with-splitview-for-windows-10-apps/